# ChartJs x-axis label to be in dateTime format issue: DD-MMM-YYYY, but displayed as MMM-YYYY-DD

Tags: datetime, label, chart.js

I am having the date value to be displayed on the x-axis in the following format: DD-MMM-YYYY. When I am passing these values, I am getting the MMM-YYYY-DD format from ChartJS.

Could you please let me know how to resolve this issue?
Many thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your x-axis is already defined as a [time cartesian axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html), you can define the option [`time.displayFormats.day`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#display-formats) in order to see the date in the desired format.

This could look as follows:

```
xAxes: [{
  type: 'time',
  time: {
    unit: 'day',
    displayFormats: {
      day: 'DD-MMM-YYYY'
    },
    tooltipFormat: 'DD-MMM-YYYY'
  }
}]
```